# How to stop inserting duplicate records before saving in db?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to save students records, but it should not take duplicate records. How is it possible? In below code i have tried to do

```
app.post("/save",function(req,res){

    var std=new student(req.body);
    student.findOne({},function(err,success){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            // console.log(success);
            std.save(function(err,success){
            if(err)
                {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            else
                {
                    console.log("inserted");
                    console.log(success);
                }
            });

        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Why not use indexing?. That would be a lot faster. Create unique index on the field which determines duplication. Check this out https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#index-type-unique

Comment: I am wondering whether the answer was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code. Please note that the existence of the value in MongoDB database depends on the `req.body` as mentioned in the OP.

In the below code, I have only name attribute in the `Student` collection. So, the duplicate check is based on the name attribute only.

You may need to change the code if you would like to check for the specific attribute in the collection to determine the duplicate value.

Please note that my `Student` collection has only attribute in the schema as well.

```
var express = require('express');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var Student = mongoose.model('Student', { name: String });
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var urlencoded_body_parser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(urlencoded_body_parser);

app.post("/save", function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body);
    var student = new Student(req.body);
    Student.findOne(req.body, function (err, success) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log(success);
            if (success == null) {
                student.save(function (err, success) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        res.send(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("inserted");
                        console.log(success);
                        res.send("success");
                    }
                });

            } else {
                res.send("Student already present");
            }

        }
    })
});

app.listen(3000);
```

**Output:-**

**First time execution:-**

**Input:-**

```
{
    "name" : "john"
}
```

**Output:-**

```
success
```

**Subsequent executions with the same input json:-**

**Output:-**

```
Student already present
```

Comment: you have done for only name attributes but i need to check it different attributes

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned the same in the answer. Currently, the code would check for all the attributes in the request body. Also, my schema and request body has only one attribute at the moment. The above solution is just the template which you can use and modify based on your requirement.

Comment: @kishore If you want to check multiple different attributes, that's an important requirement: you should edit the question to explain exactly what you need the code to do.